# Undefined Method in rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm running an integration test in rspec and the test keeps throwing up an undefined method on `billed_for`:

"undefined method `billed_for` nil:NilClass"

```
require 'user'

describe "Integration" do
  let(:user) { User.new(voucher) }

  context 'no voucher' do
    let(:voucher) { nil }

    it 'should bill default price all the time' do
      user.bill
      expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 6.95
    end
  end
end
```

I have a very small user class so far

```
require 'order'
require 'voucher'

class User
  attr_accessor :voucher, :orders

  def initialize(orders = [], voucher = nil)
    @voucher = voucher
    @orders = [orders]
  end

  def bill
    new_order = Order.new(self)
    @orders << new_order
  end
end
```

and an equally small order class:

```
class Order
  DEFAULT_PRICE = 6.95

  attr_accessor :user

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def billed_for
    price = DEFAULT_PRICE
    user.orders.each do |order|
        price - order.billed_for
    end
    price
  end
end
```

What's confusing me most is this line

```
user.orders[0].billed_for
```

when I think it through a new user class is set up this let, I then access the orders hash in user hash and then I'm accessing the `billed_for` method within the order class.

When I've googled this issue it's pointed towards using the self keyword that isn't working.

If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be great

EDIT:

Jakob S kindly pointed at that my test was failing because of nil entries in my array.

A quick an dirty fix for this was just to run the compact function to remove the nil entry.

Always open to better solutions of course.

EDIT 2:

```
let(:user) { User.new(voucher) }

context 'no voucher' do
  let(:voucher) { nil }

  it 'should bill default price all the time' do
      user.bill
      expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 6.95
      ... ...
  end
end

context 'vouchers' do
  describe 'default vouchers' do
    let(:voucher) { Voucher.create(:default, credit: 15) }

    it 'should not bill user if has a remaining credit' do
      user.bill
      expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 0.0
      ... ...
    end
  end
```

Thanks for the help so far. I've also opened an additional thread as I had a few other similar questions

[Accessing variables of other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316508/accessing-variables-and-their-scope)

Comment: In the tests are orders ever passed in to the `User` initialize method ? seems like the initialize should just set it to an empty array and not pass the value in?

Comment: I've added an example of the test flow! It looks like orders are only initliased by the user class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you instantiate your `user`, you use

```
let(:user) { User.new(voucher) }
```

`voucher` is defined as `nil` in

```
let(:voucher) { nil }
```

In other words you instantiate your `user` variable with `User.new(nil)`.

Your `User` constructor has the signature

```
def initialize(orders = [], voucher = nil)
```

so by doing `User.new(nil)` you're setting the `orders` argument to `nil` (`voucher` is also `nil`, but that's by default). Your constructor then goes ahead and creates an instance variable, `@orders` that it sets to `[orders]` - which in this case is the same as `[nil]`.

Your test then goes ahead and adds a new order to the `@orders` Array, which is fine, and that leaves your `@orders` array containing `[nil, instance_of(Order)]`.

Finally, the test tries to send the `billed_for` method to the first elements in the `orders` array: `user.orders[0].billed_for`. The orders array contains `[nil, instance_of(Order)]`, the first element of that is `nil`, thus you're actually calling

```
nil.billed_for
```

in your spec, which results in the error you're seeing.

I think you might get a bit closer to what you're looking for by not passing the `voucher` to the `orders` argument when instantiating the `User`. Also your test might want to check the last element, ie `user.orders.last` rather than `user.orders[0]`. And I suspect you might stumble across a few more improvements as you go along.

Comment: It's always something insanely simple. Thank you so much. I should mention that this a coding exercise so I'm not able to change the unit spec! But thank you for such a detailed answer. 

Did you mean not passing in order instead of voucher? I'm trying to think of a good way of not creating the array in the initializer but I'm not to sure. If I was thinking in another language I'd probably just create array empty instead of with a nil value, or make sure the nil  value is skipped etc etc. Could I possibly bother you for one more poke in the right direction?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is what would be the best way to avoid this initialisation issue? I imagine, creating the array outside of the constructor would be a start but not sure where...

Comment: Passing orders to the initializer is perfectly fine. You want to assign it to the instance variable doing `@orders = orders` instead of `@orders = [orders]`, though. The latter will wrap the array of orders in another array, which isn't what you want.

Comment: I thought the @orders array contained an instance of a single order object? This is exactly what I want as the customer can have multiple orders and the test would loop through these

Comment: Certainly, if you pass an instance of `Order` to the `orders` parameter when creating your `User`, `@orders` will be an `Array` containing that one `Order` instance. However, the parameter name `orders` being plural and the default value being `[]` indicates that the parameter should be given an array. You then put that array inside an array and store the value in `@orders`, which might or might not be what you want. But we're probably getting outside the scope of the question here.

Comment: Right! I see exactly what you mean now. orders is an array and then I'm putting it into the @orders in brackets as an array entry!
I've found that the issue is an undefined method on << when trying to push a new order in. So it's probably not being set as an array correctly :S hmmmm