# Accessing variables of other classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I received some excellent help on my last post ([Undefined Method in rspec testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273454/undefined-method-in-rspec-testing)) but I was just looking for a bit more help.

I have an rspec integration spec that I basically need to alter code for to get the desired outcome. I cannot alter the spec as it's part of the exercise.

```
let(:user) { User.new(voucher) }

context 'no voucher' do
  let(:voucher) { nil }

  it 'should bill default price all the time' do
      user.bill
      expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 6.95
      ... ...
  end
end

context 'vouchers' do
  describe 'default vouchers' do
    let(:voucher) { Voucher.create(:default, credit: 15) }

    it 'should not bill user if has a remaining credit' do
      user.bill
      expect(user.orders[0].billed_for).to eql 0.0
      ... ...
    end
  end
```

I placed some dots just to cut out the unnecessary code.

I pretty much understand what's happen here.

A new user class is being create and set to :user in let. A voucher is then initiliased and passed in depending on the context. no voucher is set for the first test. One is set for the second.

Here's where my questions begin

```
require 'order'
require 'voucher'

class User
  attr_accessor :voucher, :orders

  def initialize(orders = [], voucher = nil)
    @voucher = voucher
    @orders = [orders]
  end

  def bill
    new_order = Order.new(self)
    @orders << new_order
  end
end
```

The method is initliased. It has optional parameters. I'm a little unclear on how the initialisation works though as I'm unable to access these set variables at all anywhere.

I'm a little unsure about the scope limitations though as I'm hoping to access some of the vouchers variables from the order class which currently looks like this

```
class Order
  DEFAULT_PRICE = 6.95

  attr_accessor :user

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def billed_for
    price = DEFAULT_PRICE
    user.orders.each do |order|
        price - order.billed_for
    end
    price
  end
end
```

shoudl accessing the users voucher class be as easy as user.voucher. ??

Also a smaller question. I'm currently using a factory method so the voucher class can initialise itself.

```
 def self.create(type, *attrs)
```

the *attrs parameter is essentially an array. I can loop through this and bind it to some expected variables by checking for their presence. ie if array has certain key set this key's value to a variable. Is this the best way or is there another popular way?

I know this is a lot to ask but I'm finding myself really confused and would be grateful if annyone could clear any of this up me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the `User` class you can access the `voucher` and `orders` variables as they are instance variables and publicly accessible due to the `attr_accessor` at the top.

For your factory problem I recommend **[FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)** from Thoughbot it makes building Factory objects very easy.  You can also use Rails *Fixtures* which are static data you create.

Comment: I'm just a little unclear about how I'd access this in another class. user.voucher should return it's value right? Or am I missing something

Comment: It would return the `voucher` object or `nil` if there isn't a voucher for the user.  You could assign the `voucher` to a variable and then access it's properties using the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was initializing the variables in the wrong order. This meant that I was looking for items in the wrong class.

Embarrassing noob mistake! All the better for it :)